# Опечатка на странице Справка > Как задавать вопросы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Опечатка на странице [Справка > Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), по идее вместо *вопрос*, должно быть слово *ответ*.

> Для того, чтобы отметить **вопрос** принятым, нажмите на серую галку
>   рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ
>   отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или
>   отметить ею другой ответ.

P.S.: не знаю какую еще метку можно добавить к такому сообщению.

Comment: К такого рода дефектам следует добавлять метку [meta-tag:дефект] и, если это переводная статья, то ещё [meta-tag:локализация].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень интересная опечатка. Спасибо! Поправил!